# why does my directive throws $unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

unknown provider  error:
 [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?   p0=postbuttonsProvider%20%3C-%20postbuttons%20%3C-%20RandomBusinessCtrl

here is my code : the directive is defined as follows :

```
angular.module('home', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','ngDialog'])

.directive("postbutton", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    bindToController: true,
    template: "<button>Post review</button>"        
}
})

.controller('RandomBusinessCtrl', 
    ['$scope','postbutton','pickRandomBusinesses','BusinessViewModel','config',
    function ($scope,postbutton,pickRandomBusinesses,BusinessViewModel,config) {

    });
```

my html is :

```
<div ng-controller="RandomBusinessCtrl">
<span class="badge pull-right" style="background-color:#CB525B;" >
      <postbuttons></postbuttons>
    <!-- <button type="button" value="post_business" style="background-color:#CB525B; height:15px;border:0px;`" ng-click="postReview(random_business.id,user_id,rate,price,date_created,details)">Post review</button> -->
  </span>
```

Comment: Please add some more code or provide a plunker

Comment: you cannot inject directive inside the controller......remove postbutton from RandomBusinessCtrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does my directive throws $unknown provider

Because you are trying inject directive into controller. It doesn't make sense - you can only inject services.

Why directives are not injectable? Clearly, one might want to use its API from controller? Well, the reason why is the core or Angular app architecture. Directives being part of view layer of the application, should not be interacted from controller directly. Another important thing to understand is that services (what you inject) is intentionally singletones - while directives cannot be, of course.

In your case you don't need to worry about it: directive is registered on the same module so it's available in template.

Correct controller definition would be:

```
.controller('RandomBusinessCtrl' [
    '$scope', 'pickRandomBusinesses', 'BusinessViewModel', 'config',
    function ($scope, pickRandomBusinesses, BusinessViewModel, config) {

});
```

Comment: Man you are the best.. Thanks alot ..for the information ..though i lost my button cant see it on the interface anymore

Comment: Glad it was useful. Why your button is gone - something is with your app, from the posted code it's not possible to say.

Comment: i think the name of tag and directive doesn't match